# How to optimize this code for memory and run time?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a code which takes two input:
First input t is for taking the number of test cases
Then t times the loop will run and each time it will take a non-negative integer.
So for each non-negative integer taken as input, I need to count odd 0s and odd 1s bits in its binary form.

Logically the code which I have written is giving me correct output as expected, but memory-wise and time-wise its not much optimized.
Memory limit- 5Mb

```
def _subString(num): 
    # my_dir = dir()
    binary_num = bin(num)[2:]
    s = str(binary_num)
    n = len(s)
    count_1 = 0
    count_0 = 0
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(i+1,n+1): 
            sub = s[i: j]
            c_1 = sub.count('1')
            c_0 = sub.count('0')
            if c_1 % 2 != 0:
                count_1 += 1
            if c_0 % 2 != 0:
                count_0 += 1
    print(count_0, count_1)
    # del s,n,count_1,count_0,sub,c_1,c_0
    # for varis in dir():
    #     if varis not in my_dir and varis != "my_dir":
    #         exec("%s = None" % str(varis))
    # for name in dir():
    #     if not name.startswith('_'):
    #         del locals()[name]

_t = int(input())
for x in range(_t):
    my_dir = dir()
    _subString(int(input()))
    for varis in dir():
        if not varis.startswith('_') and varis != "my_dir":
            exec("%s = None" % str(varis))
```

Comment: maybe this type of question is better suited to the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can we move it to there? any option as such @3NiGMa